# How to retrieve data from SQLite and add it to edittext in other activity

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-edittext, data-retrieval

How to retrieve data from SQLite and add it to edittext in other activity.

frome a register user page i insert data to sqlite. now i want to have  user info page to display this data in edit text so that user may update it

Comment: If you want to be notified instantly from the user info page automatically, then you can try livedata & viewmodel. If not, you can just retrieve the data after some time using cursor from your database helper.

Comment: What is the problem ? Why this https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#ReadDbRow does not help ? (or u can find same tutorial for room )